Character's leg/armor touch during posing for walk cycle
Posing my character doing a walk cycle is causing his leg to touch. File: https://we.tl/t-4aF7llTR5x


I suspect it's because these vertices are connected but I'm not sure how to disconnect them without messing up the armor. Thank you.



The vertex you show is part of the 2 boots, also the 2 boots are intersecting even before the animation, you should remove it, maybe move a bit apart the 2 boots and redo the topology
